# adding x-www-form-urlencoded to post request

Tags: python

[example from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Flwf5.png)

```
import urllib2
url = "http://www.example.com/posts"
    
req = urllib2.Request(url,headers={'User-Agent' : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.04 Chromium/12.0.742.112 Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30" , "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
con = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print con.read()
```

now this code works fine but i want to add the value as you see in postman picture to get the response that i want i don't know how to add the key and value `postid = 134686`  to python and it's post request in postman

Comment: Does the id have to be in URL posts or in payload body ?

Comment: i think in the payload body

Comment: Is the POST request from postman client working for you ?

Comment: no the website i'm dealing with have thousands of postid values i can open them with manipulating tamper data value to get the response or postman now i just want to pass this postid to my python code so i can get the same response that i get in postman

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Form-encoded is the normal way to send a POST request with data. Just supply a `data` dict; you don't even need to specify the content-type.

```
data = {'postid': 134786}
headers = {'User-Agent' : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.04 Chromium/12.0.742.112 Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30"}
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Comment: Media type is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" , so data can be a of dict ? Generally, server takes it in form x=y.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The whole point of requests is that it makes it easy to do the common things like posting data, by transforming it into the correct format for you.

Comment: i tried your code but it gives me an error TypeError: sendall() argument 1 must be string or buffer, not dict

Comment: try `data="postid=x"` instead of a `dict`

Comment: @chinmay thanks everything is working fine now thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Just to an important thing to note is that for nested json data you will need to convert the nested json object to string.

```
data = { 'key1': 'value',
         'key2': {
                'nested_key1': 'nested_value1',
                'nested_key2': 123
         }

       }
```

The dictionary needs to be transformed in this format

```
inner_dictionary = {
                'nested_key1': 'nested_value1',
                'nested_key2': 123
         }


data = { 'key1': 'value',
         'key2': json.dumps(inner_dictionary)

       }

r = requests.post(URL, data = data)
```